# VBA array dimensions causing runtime error 9 for simulation application

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, matrix

I am working on a simulation with time to event data that requires some "memory" of when an event started in order to apply a Weibull function at that time. This requires a large matrix of values and I am interested a VBA solution to avoid large conditional and array calculations on the worksheet. The current solution is to create a matrix containing the data and to multiply that by a matrix containing the diagonal of interest and then sum the product to obtain the diagonal alone. The matrix is 1800x1800 on the sheet.

The code below appears to fault during the matrix multiplication and gives a "run time error '9' subscript of of range" message. I have found that 'array_2' -despite being specified as array_2(1,1) -shows as having a lower bound of 1 and upper bound of 2 (see block of code near the bottom for proof).

Any help as to why this is occurring would be much appreciated.

Todd

```
Sub sum_diag_float()

Dim a, b, q, i, j, x, y, lb, ub, sum As Double

Dim array_1(), array_2(), upright_arr(), array_product() As Variant

ReDim array_1(0 To 9, 0 To 9) As Variant

    'create data
        For a = 0 To 9
            For b = 0 To 9
                array_1(a, b) = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 10)
                Next b
            Next a
        Range("A1:J10").Value = array_1



For q = 1 To 1

    ReDim array_2(q, q) As Variant
        array_2 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(q + 1, q + 1)).Value
            Range(Cells(1, 12), Cells(2, 13)).Value = array_2           'check array specification

            'build binary matrix (0/1) from lower left to upper right
                ReDim upright_arr(q, q) As Variant
                    For i = LBound(upright_arr, 1) To UBound(upright_arr, 1)
                        For j = LBound(upright_arr, 2) To UBound(upright_arr, 2)

                            If UBound(upright_arr, 2) = i + j Then
                                upright_arr(i, j) = 1
                            Else
                                upright_arr(i, j) = 0
                            End If

                        Next j
                    Next i
                Range(Cells(4, 12), Cells(5, 13)).Value = upright_arr   'check matrix specification

            'multiply data by the matrix
                ReDim array_product(q, q) As Variant

                    For x = LBound(upright_arr, 1) To UBound(upright_arr, 1)
                        For y = LBound(upright_arr, 2) To UBound(upright_arr, 2)
                            array_product(x, y) = upright_arr(x, y) * array_2(x, y)
                        Next y
                    Next x
                Range(Cells(7, 12), Cells(8, 13)).Value = array_product 'matrix multiplication result
                sum = WorksheetFunction.sum(array_product)
                Range("N9").Value = sum                                 'sum of matrix

                lb = LBound(array_2, 1) 'proof of array dimension misspecification
                Range("L11").Value = lb
                ub = UBound(array_2, 1)
                Range("L12").Value = ub
                lb = LBound(array_2, 2)
                Range("L14").Value = lb
                ub = UBound(array_2, 2)
                Range("L15").Value = ub

    Next q

End Sub
```

The edited code following the first suggestions retains a runtime error '13' :

```
Sub sum_diag_float()

Dim a As Byte, b As Byte
Dim q As Double, i As Double, j As Double, x As Double, y As Double
Dim lb As Double, ub As Double, sum As Double

Dim array_1() As Double, array_2() As Double, upright_arr() As Double, array_product() As Double

ReDim array_1(0 To 9, 0 To 9) As Double

'create data
    For a = 0 To 9
        For b = 0 To 9
            array_1(a, b) = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 10)
            Next b
        Next a
    Range("A1:J10").Value = array_1

For q = 1 To 2

ReDim array_2(q, q) As Double
    array_2 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(q + 1, q + 1)).Value             'put cells in array
        Range(Cells(1, 12), Cells(1 + q, 12 + q)).Value = array_2       'check array 

'build binary matrix (0/1) from lower left to upper right
ReDim upright_arr(LBound(array_2, 1) To UBound(array_2, 1), LBound(array_2, 2) _ 
     To UBound(array_2, 2)) As Double
     For i = LBound(array_2, 1) To UBound(array_2, 1)
         For j = LBound(array_2, 2) To UBound(array_2, 2)

                        If UBound(upright_arr, 2) = i + j - 1 Then
                            upright_arr(i, j) = 1
                        Else
                            upright_arr(i, j) = 0
                        End If

                    Next j
                Next i
            Range(Cells(5, 12), Cells(5 + q, 12 + q)).Value = upright_arr

        'multiply data by the matrix
        ReDim array_product(LBound(array_2, 1) To UBound(array_2, 1), LBound(array_2, 2) _
                To UBound(array_2, 2)) As Double
           For x = LBound(array_2, 1) To UBound(array_2, 1)
                For y = LBound(array_2, 2) To UBound(array_2, 2)
                    array_product(x, y) = upright_arr(x, y) * array_2(x, y)
                 Next y
             Next x

            Range(Cells(9, 12), Cells(9 + q, 12 + q)).Value = array_product
            sum = WorksheetFunction.sum(array_product)
            Range("O12").Value = sum                                 'sum of matrix

Next q

End Sub
```

After correcting the above issues, the array multiplication step bugs to a run-time error '13' when used in the following code. I believe some variable is not being erased when called twice via the first sub. In reading various documentation, I do not beleive that I should have to provide any of the values to the call to 'sum_diag_float,' but this may be the problem. Ultimately, the sub 'call_txp_surv' will be called within other loops to create the desired simulation data, thus the need for the sub to work without bugs despite the number of times it is called.  I am noting that a call_txp_surv  with q = 1000 (s = 1000) does not generate an error, but at q = 1800 and s= 1800 the run-time '13' occurs.  The code now contains the implemented cell counts which are different from previous code (much larger and thus no simulated data). Variables/counters have been renamed to avoid conflict with others. Any thoughts as to why this macro won't scale-up would be appreciated.

```
Sub call_txp_surv()

Dim lvad_clvad As Byte

For lvad_clvad = 1 To 2
    If lvad_clvad = 1 Then
        Worksheets("LVAD>TXP>death").Activate
    Else
        Worksheets("cLVAD>TXP>death").Activate
    End If

    Call sum_diag_float

Next lvad_clvad

End Sub


Sub sum_diag_float()

Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim a As Byte, b As Byte
Dim m As Long, n As Long, q As Long, x As Long, y As Long

Dim array_1() As Double, array_2() As Variant, upright_arr() As Variant, array_product() As Variant


'cycle living calculation

    For q = 1 To 1800

    'put cells into array
        array_2 = Range(Cells(3, 20), Cells(3 + q, 20 + q)).Value

    'build binary matrix (0/1) from lower left to upper right
        ReDim upright_arr(LBound(array_2, 1) To UBound(array_2, 1), LBound(array_2, 2) To UBound(array_2, 2)) As Variant
            For m = LBound(array_2, 1) To UBound(array_2, 1)
                For n = LBound(array_2, 2) To UBound(array_2, 2)

                    If UBound(upright_arr, 2) = m + n - 1 Then
                        upright_arr(m, n) = 1
                    Else
                        upright_arr(m, n) = 0
                    End If

                Next n
            Next m

    'multiply data by the matrix
            ReDim array_product(LBound(array_2, 1) To UBound(array_2, 1), LBound(array_2, 2) To UBound(array_2, 2)) As Variant
                For x = LBound(array_2, 1) To UBound(array_2, 1)
                    For y = LBound(array_2, 2) To UBound(array_2, 2)
                        array_product(x, y) = upright_arr(x, y) * array_2(x, y)
                    Next y
                Next x

            'Range(Cells(9, 12), Cells(9 + q, 12 + q)).Value = array_product 'matrix multiplication result
            sum = WorksheetFunction.sum(array_product)
            Cells(4 + q, 1821).Value = sum                               'sum of matrix
    Next q



'cycle deaths
Dim c As Long, d As Long, s As Long, t As Long, u As Double, diff As Double

s = 1801

'subtract
    For c = 1 To s
        For d = 1 To (s - c)
            diff = Cells(2 + d, 19 + c).Value - Cells(3 + d, 19 + c).Value
            Cells(4 + d + (c - 1), 1823 + c).Value = diff
        Next d
    Next c

'sum
    For t = 1 To (s - 1)
        u = WorksheetFunction.sum(Range(Cells(4 + t, t + 1823), Cells(4 + t, t + 1824)))
        Cells(4 + t, 1822).Value = u
    Next t

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: See comments regarding your edit in my response

Comment: Is it possible that if a cell is empty and assigned to an array that the array does not "ReDim" to the new range of (empty) cells?

Comment: What happened when you tried that?  Show me the code you ran that resulted in the array not ReDim ing

Comment: Running an attempt just below the last line.

Comment: Assuring the for loop did not require population of an empty array completed the task to 1790 rows. I will have to fuss with it to get it dialed in exactly, but my assumption is that the arrays were not being redimensioned somehow. I'm not sure why this would be the case, as all other arrays are dimensioned according to 'array_2.' However, this seems to be the case.

Comment: If you are having a problem and need help, you will have to post the relevant code and be specific as to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code line:

```
ReDim array_2(q, q) As Variant
```

dimensions array_2 as (0 to 1, 0 to 1)

But then your next line:

```
array_2 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(q + 1, q + 1)).Value
```

actually redimensions array_2 to (1 to 2, 1 to 2) (two rows and two columns) (Dimension 1 for the rows; Dimension 2 for the columns).

This is what happens when you set an array equal to a range of cells.

If you want to retain the 0 to 1 dimensions, you would have to loop through the cells and assign them specifically.

See  [Arrays and Ranges in VBA by Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

As an aside, your line:

```
Dim a, b, q, i, j, x, y, lb, ub, sum As Double
```

declares all of the variables, except for sum , as Variants.  Given your code, I wonder if they should be declared as Long.

**EDIT:**  With regard to your edited code, I don't understand why you did what you did.

- In the link I posted above to Chip Pearson's website, it clearly shows that, when you are setting an array equal to a range, the array should be declared as type Variant; you have declared it as Double (twice!), therefore the Type Mismatch error.  Again, if you MUST have the array as type Double, then you will have to loop through and assign the values one by one.
- For reasons I wrote above, the *ReDim array_2* line adds overhead without accomplishing anything and should be removed.
- Why do you declare your counters as being of type Double instead of type Long?

Comment: Ron, I appreciate your suggestions. These have resolved many issues. The key to a working solution was declaring new arrays by the Lbound, Ubound function for all arrays following the re-dimensioned array_2. I changed most of the data types to double, however this now creates a "runtime error '13' " at the line: `array_2 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(q + 1, q + 1)).Value` Any notion of what is responsible? There are no empty or non-numeric fields in the referenced range on the sheet. Thanks-

Comment: @Todd See comments regarding your modified code in my Answer

Answer (score 0):

The working and tested code for my question is below. Thanks to Ron for assisting.

```
Sub sum_diag_float()

Dim a As Byte, b As Byte
Dim q As Long, i As Long, j As Long, x As Long, y As Long

Dim array_1() As Double, array_2() As Variant, upright_arr() As Double, array_product() As Double

ReDim array_1(0 To 9, 0 To 9) As Double

    'create data
        For a = 0 To 9
            For b = 0 To 9
                array_1(a, b) = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 10)
                Next b
            Next a
        Range("A1:J10").Value = array_1

For q = 1 To 2

        array_2 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(q + 1, q + 1)).Value             'put cells in array
            Range(Cells(1, 12), Cells(1 + q, 12 + q)).Value = array_2       'check array specification

            'build binary matrix (0/1) from lower left to upper right
                ReDim upright_arr(LBound(array_2, 1) To UBound(array_2, 1), LBound(array_2, 2) To UBound(array_2, 2)) As Double
                    For i = LBound(array_2, 1) To UBound(array_2, 1)
                        For j = LBound(array_2, 2) To UBound(array_2, 2)

                            If UBound(upright_arr, 2) = i + j - 1 Then
                                upright_arr(i, j) = 1
                            Else
                                upright_arr(i, j) = 0
                            End If

                        Next j
                    Next i
                Range(Cells(5, 12), Cells(5 + q, 12 + q)).Value = upright_arr 'check matrix specification

            'multiply data by the matrix
                ReDim array_product(LBound(array_2, 1) To UBound(array_2, 1), LBound(array_2, 2) To UBound(array_2, 2)) As Double
                    For x = LBound(array_2, 1) To UBound(array_2, 1)
                        For y = LBound(array_2, 2) To UBound(array_2, 2)
                            array_product(x, y) = upright_arr(x, y) * array_2(x, y)
                        Next y
                    Next x

                Range(Cells(9, 12), Cells(9 + q, 12 + q)).Value = array_product 'matrix multiplication result
                sum = WorksheetFunction.sum(array_product)
                Range("O12").Value = sum                                 'sum of matrix

    Next q

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ron, The Chip Pearson site demonstrates the array behavior as you describe. Based on the text, the Variant datatype appeared to be sufficient, but not necessary.

Comment: Re-Reading the text I'd agree with you. But the behavior suggests otherwise.